# Creating custom conditional metric with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am trying to create the following metric for my neural network using keras:

[Custom Keras metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSg0o.png)

where d=y_{pred}-y_{true}

and both y_{pred} and y_{true} are vectors

With the following code:

import keras.backend as K

```
def score(y_true, y_pred):
        d=(y_pred - y_true)
        if d<0:
            return K.exp(-d/10)-1
        else:
            return K.exp(d/13)-1
```

For the use of compiling my model:

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=[score])
```

I received the following error code and I have not been able to correct the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

> raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not
>   allowed. " "Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a "
>   "tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as "
>
> TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use
>   `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined,
>   and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs
>   conditioned on the value of a tensor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metric you are providing is not a function that gets executed each time, but rather a construction of the function (computational graph) that needs to be evaluated. So it needs to be deterministic.

Try:

```
def score(y_true, y_pred):
    d = y_pred - y_true
    mask = K.less(y_pred, y_true)  # element-wise True where y_pred < y_pred
    mask = K.cast(mask, K.floatx())  # cast to 0.0 / 1.0
    s = mask * (K.exp(-d / 10) - 1) + (1 - mask) * (K.exp(d / 13) - 1)  
    # every i where mask[i] is 1, s[i] == (K.exp(-d / 10) - 1)
    # every i where mask[i] is 0, s[i] == (K.exp(d / 13) - 1)
    return s
```