# Custom Metrics Keras

Tags: keras, metrics

i need help to create a custom metrics in keras. I need to count how many times my error is equal to zero (y_pred - y_true = 0).

I tried this:

```
n_train = 1147 # Number of samples on training set
c = 0 # Variable to count
def our_metric(y_true, y_pred):
  if y_true-y_pred == 0:
    c += 1
  return c/n_train
```

But i'm getting this error:

> OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`
>   is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate
>   this function with @tf.function.

**EDIT:** Using the solution proposed here:

[Creating custom conditional metric with Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902088/creating-custom-conditional-metric-with-keras?newreg=e11e214e50b24041bf97b1688c7ec16a)

I solved my problem as this:

```
c = tf.constant(0)
def our_metric(y_true, y_pred):
  mask = K.equal(y_pred, y_true) # TRUE if y_pred = y_true
  mask = K.cast(mask,K.floatx())
  s = K.sum(mask)
  return s/n_train
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accuracy metric

Comment: I used the solution proposed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902088/creating-custom-conditional-metric-with-keras?newreg=e11e214e50b24041bf97b1688c7ec16a

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Python comparison in plain `tensorflow` (using static graphs).

You have to enable `eager mode`, a wrapper which let's you use some Python control statements (like `if` or `loop`). Just decorate your function as the error suggests or issue `tf.enable_eager_execution()` at the beginning of your script.

You may also want to update your code to use `tf2.0`, it's more intuitive and has eager mode on by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to use Keras backend functions to count the number of times a value is equal to zero. You just have to think a bit outside of the box. Here is an example:

```
diff = y_true - y_pred
count = K.sum(K.cast(K.equal(diff, K.zeros_like(diff)), 'int8'))
```

There's also a `tf.count_nonzero` operation that could be used, but mixing keras and explicit tensorflow can cause issues.